# Expected value of picking one rope end of $2n-1$ rope ends

Tags: probability

There are $n$ ropes in a bucket. From $n-1$ ropes you can reach both rope ends. Only one rope is knotted to the bottom of the bucket. Therefore you can reach $2n-1$ rope ends. You pick randomly one rope end and pull the rope out until you pick the rope that is knotted to the bottom. Let $X$ be the number of ropes you pull out before picking the one rope. What is the expected value of $X$?

I tried to calculate the probabilty that the one rope is picked as the i-th rope. $P[X_i] = \prod_{k=1}^{i-1}\left( \frac{2n-2k}{2n-(2k-1)}\right) * \frac{1}{2n-(2i-1)}.$
Then for the expectetd value $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}((i-1)*P[X_i]),$ 
which gets a little bit complicated. Is there a more comfortable way of doing this?

Comment: Is your problem equivalent to the following problem?

"""There are $n-1$ black balls and $1$ white ball in a bucket. You pull out balls until you pick the white one. What's the expected number of black balls pulled out?"""

Comment: It is similar but the difference is that you have $2n-1$ black balls and remove 2 black balls each time you pick a black one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E(X_n)=\frac 23n+\frac13$$
We have $E(X_n)=\frac 1{2n-1}+\frac {2n-2}{2n-1}(1+E(X_{n-1}))=1+\frac {2n-2}{2n-1}E(X_{n-1})$ because when you pull the first end you have $\frac 1{2n-1}$ chance of getting the tied rope and otherwise you used a move and have the case with one less rope. $E(X_1)=1$ as you only have the tied rope end available.  This is the base case of our induction.  Now let it be true up to $k$.  We have $$\begin {align}E(X_{k+1})&=1+\frac {2k}{2k+1}E(X_k)\\&=1+\frac {2k}{2k+1}\left(\frac 23k+\frac 13\right)\\&=\frac {6k+3+4k^2+2k}{3(2k+1)}\\&=\frac {2k+3}3\\&=\frac 23(k+1)+\frac 13 \end {align}$$